# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in my JavaScript file

Tags: javascript

I am facing this console error while running my application:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

It is showing in my HYPE.js file at the following line:

```
for(;0<window.HYPE_100_DocumentsToLoad.length;)window.HYPE_100_DocumentsToLoad[0](),window.HYPE_100_DocumentsToLoad.splice(0,1);})();
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question with fiddle or plunker.
Mostly error occurs when an array is undefined

Comment: As per the error, it seems the array is undefined. Can you paste code snippet where it is defined?

Answer (score 2):

The error happens because `window.HYPE_100_DocumentsToLoad` is `undefined`.

You should make sure it actually *is an array* before using it as such:

```
if (Array.isArray(window.HYPE_100_DocumentsToLoad)) {
    for(;0<window.HYPE_100_DocumentsToLoad.length;)window.HYPE_100_DocumentsToLoad[0](),window.HYPE_100_DocumentsToLoad.splice(0,1);})();
} else {
    throw new Error("Not an array, cannot loop over it");
}
```